# Menus and toolbar

Tags: python, pyside, menubar, qwidget, qmainwindow

I am new in programming and I have created a simple application with one class in Python and PySide which manipulates phone bill csv files. Now I want an option for mobile too.

How can I add a menubar, when my class inherits from QWidget? Should I write another class which inherits from QMainWindow and then make an instance of my first class as a central widget? Is this the right way to do this?

```
class MyWidget(QtGui.QWidget):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MyWidget, self).__init__(parent)
        ....


class MyWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MyWindow, self).__init__(parent)

        widget = MyWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(widget)
        ...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no need for a `QMainWindow`, you can simply create a `QMenuBar` in your widget.

```
class MyWidget(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MyWidget, self).__init__(parent)
        self.menu=QtGui.QMenuBar()
        self.menu.addAction("do something")
        layout=QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.menu)
```

A `QMainWindow` is basically a widget which already has a layout with a menu bar, a toolbar, a status bar, etc. If you don't need all of those functionality, you can use a simple `QWidget` and add only what you want.